# Add and initialize custom field in Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, model, django-1.11

I feel like I am missing some very basic point, but can't solve this.
Let's say I have model like this one:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    # this is weird field, but needed for my usecase
    last_name = models.WeirdCustomField(max_length=256, blank=True)
```

And there is a form for this, which I would like to customize a bit (comments):

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        # I want to override 'last_name' field, so exclude it here
        exclude = ['last_name']

    # And add additional field
    my_field = ChoiceField(choices=list_of_choicec)
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        last_name = kwargs.pop('last_name', None)
        my_field = kwargs.pop('my_field', None)
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['last_name'] = last_name
        self.fields['my_field'] = my_field
```

Now, in the `shell` (after all imports...)

```
person = Person.objects.get(first_name='Jacob')
person.first_name # Prints 'Jacob', correct!
form = PersonForm(instance=person, last_name='Smith', my_field='test123')
form['first_name'].value() # -> 'Jacob', that's right
form['last_name'].value() # -> nothing, I expected 'Smith'
form['my_field'].value() # -> nothing, I would like to see 'test123'
```

I think I dig Internet very deep, but could not find solutions for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the initial value. In your init try replace with below code.

```
self.fields['last_name'].initial = last_name
self.fields['my_field'].initial = my_field
```

The initial can also be passed when the form instance is created.

```
form = PersonForm(instance=person, initial={'last_name'='Smith', 'my_field'='test123'})
```

This one is the recommended way to do it. Don't have to override the init method at all.

Comment: Amazing, I don't think I would figure it out myself in the near future, thank you! I also need to say, it is quite counter intuitive, but I guess it's the framework way.

Comment: try printing self.fields['my_field'] in your init. You can see what it is.

Comment: how to perform this in generic views ??

Comment: Which generic view are you using ?